# Brushless motor vibration/jitter/noise - arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, motor, pwm, wires

I am currently using [these motors](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/2206-140kv-brushless-gimbal-motor-ideal-for-gopro-style-cameras.html) and driving them off [these drivers](https://www.iot-store.com.au/products/brushless-4-click-bldc-motor-driver?utm_campaign=order-confirmation-email&utm_medium=email&utm_content=product&utm_term=link&utm_source=OrderlyEmails) and an arduino uno, and alternatively trying to make them turn using the setup in step 6 (both with l298n and without) in [this instructable](https://www.instructables.com/DIY-Brushless-Gimbal-with-Arduino/). I have 4 motors and all are exhibiting the same behaviour.

Using the drivers, I just sent a constant PWM via PWM pin, and the motor would only spin at high values around 255, but even then only when I touch the motor does it start spinning. This spinning is then not even smooth, it pauses a bit every second or so and results in a sort of jittering. After a bit more, plugging the motors in it now just makes an increasingly louder whining noise, kind of like it's getting ready to take off but doesnt really spin. Code used here is just basic as below:

```
void setup () {

pinMode(9, OUTPUT);

}

void loop (){

analogWrite(9, 255);

}
```

Using the instructable setups, I've wired exactly the same way (wiring for l298N version is in step 10, wiring for discrete steps is just directly pwms to the motor), but the motors will not spin like theirs do (same poles and slots, 12n14p). Mine just jitters back and forth in tiny steps and looks like it's just twitching. Code used is exactly as at the end of 'step 6'.

[Imgur album of issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSQ59.jpg)

Comment: sounds like the power supply is running out of juice

Comment: put the analogWrite into setup() ... remove it from loop()